# MacBook Air M1 2020 and Cisco AnyConnect VPN shuts off after lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, vpn

I have changed my settings under as such:

[image]

[image]

Right now I have my Mac plugged in, and with these preferences the Mac should not go on sleep mode making the vpn off. Whenever I close my lid and reopen very quickly my Cisco connection basically is off immediately. The Mac is not going to sleep but nonetheless I lose connection. Is this a Cisco settings configuration that I should tweak and I'm not aware of, or is there anything else I can do on the Mac side to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342436/keep-wifi-alive-when-on-battery-and-lid-closed?rq=1